# Help understanding いいやって and いやだなって

Tags: grammar

I'm confused about the parts in bold in the sentence below:

> 山田みたいに、ぜんぜん勉強しなくて**いいやって**、わりきれるわけじゃないわりにはそれほど勉強しないし、怒られても気にしない性格じゃないし...すごく**いやだなって**思ってるのに、ついつい怒られているよ...ああ、最悪の人生だね。
>
> Like 山田, I don't study at all **???** It doesn't mean that I'm satisfied with not studying that much, and I'm not the sort of person who doesn't care about making people angry...**even though I think it's really unpleasant** ... unintentionally making people angry ... it's the worst life (my translation attempt)

My best guess at what いいやって means is "play well and..." but shouldn't that be よくやって?

As for すごくいやだなって, I'm assuming って is the quote marker for 思う. And いやだな is just いやだ (it's unpleasant) with a な on the end for emphasis.

Also, my translation of "even though" for のに seems a bit incongruous.

Please explain any errors I have made.

Comment: Can someone help me with "わりきれるわけじゃないわりにはそれほど勉強しないし"? I know わけじゃない is  "It doesn't mean that I'm satisfied", and "それほど勉強しない" is "don't study that much", but I'm not sure how わりには brings it all together.

Comment: @SenjougaharaHitagi I think the わりには is like *despite* or *although*. "I don't study that much, although I can't convince myself / be satisfied..." i.e. "I don't study that much, although I can't give up studying altogether, like Yamada does."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll elaborate on the いいや.

From [大辞林](http://www.excite.co.jp/dictionary/japanese/?itemid=DJR_ya_-130):

> #### や
>
> ㊃（終助）② 軽く言い放つような気持ち，または，なげやりな気持ちを表す。
>   「まあ，いい**や**」 「今さらどうしようもない**や**」

The `〜や` adds an “oh well” or a “whatever” kind of sentiment. You use it like you would use `〜よ`, but **to yourself** and with a sense of resignation.

いい can sometimes be safely translated to “don't mind”, but perhaps it would be easier to just think of it as an “okay”:

> A: ここ座って**いい**？ *(Is it okay if I sit here?)*
>   B: **いい**よ *(Okay)*

Then, when you're telling **yourself** that something is okay, you might say:

> このベンチ汚いけど座っていいかな？ **いいや**、座っちゃおう。
>   *This bench is dirty, is it okay if I sit? Okay, what the heck, I'll sit.*

Answer (score 1):

As for the part of `ぜんぜん勉強しなくていいやって`, `って` is the quote mark, same as `いやだなって思ってる`.
`いいや` can be divided into `いい` and `や`.
`いい` has a meaning of `I don't mind`, and `や` is just an auxiliary verb.
Therefore, the translation of `ぜんぜん勉強しなくていいやって` will be `I don't mind if I do not study at all`.

As for `すごくいやだなって`, your guess is completely correct.

My translation is:

Not like 山田, I can not consider studying as trivial matters.
But, considering this, I do not study that much, and I am not the person who do not care about getting scolded...
I feel getting scold is very undesirable, but I somehow being scolded... it's the worst life.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've never seen いい used to mean "don't mind" before and I've never seen やる used as an auxilliary verb without て. What is the function of the auxilliary verb in this case? I can't find any other examples of this. Could you provide a simple example of how to say "I don't mind ..." using this grammar? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the や in question here is just colloquial/kansai-ben for だ. It doesn't really have anything to do with やる.

Comment: でも・・・「いいだ」って言わないし・・・（「いいんだ」(関東)「いいんや」(関西)なら言うけど）