# Meaning of しなくていいやって

Tags: grammar

A while ago as part of [another question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/29068/help-understanding-this-sentence-please) I asked about the bold part of this sentence:

> 山田みたいに、ぜんぜん勉強しなくて**いいやって**、...
>
> Like 山田 I don't study at all and ???...

I was told that "いいや can be divided into いい and や. いい has a meaning of I don't mind, and や is just an auxiliary verb", and that って was the quote marker. So the sentence meant "(I don't mind if I do not study at all (like 山田)"

Whilst the translation seems to make sense I still don't understand the grammar and how to use it in other sentences. Can someone please provide further clarification?

1. Surely や isn't a verb on its own it has to be やる doesn't it?
2. ..which means that って is just the te-form rather than the quote marker?
3. If って is the quote marker then what is the ellipted verb?
4. Is いい 'good' or the stem form of 言う or something else. I'm assuming 'good' makes most sense, but I've never seen an adjective modify a verb before.?

Basically I haven't got a clue how to make sense of this grammar. Please help.

Comment: Sounds like a collocal version of いいよ and って　is the quote marker.
I've already said that it's okay not to learn at all, just like Yamada.

Comment: The や is a 終助詞. ➌-2  "軽く言い放すような気持ちを表す。「もう、どうでもいいや」" ([デジタル大辞泉](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/220994/meaning/m0u/%E3%82%84/))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about parsing it this way:

> [（山田みたいに、「ぜんぜん勉強しなくていいや。」って、わりきれる）わけじゃない]わりには・・・

Literally: Although it's not that I can convince myself (thinking) "I don't have to study at all!" like Yamada, ...

1. The や is a 終助詞(sentence-ending particle).
2. The って is quotative (≒ と). You can rephrase this part as:

   > 「ぜんぜん勉強しなくていいや。」と、わりきれる
3. ～～と割り切る (≒ ～～と言って/思って 割り切る) "convince oneself / be satisfied, thinking / saying ~~"
4. The いい (良い) means *okay* or *doesn't matter*. しなくていい means "don't have to~~".